# Getting raw XML data from a Feedburner RSS feed

Tags: rss, feedburner

For an Android app I am currently working on, I would like to be able to parse raw XML data from an RSS feed and display it. The RSS feed in question uses Feedburner for publishing, and my Google-fu has so far given me nothing on how to get the raw XML. Any tips?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try adding fmt=xml to your url. For ex: http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogname?fmt=xml.

I am having other strange problems for iOS SDK using XPathQuery to extract data from the response.

Comment: We ended up asking the admin of the site for access to his XMLRPC connection so we could ask for data directly. This did work for me though. Thank you

Comment: Does not work for http://feeds.feedburner.com/dubstepnet  Potentially disabled by the publisher?

Comment: Is there a new method for accomplishing this? Setting fmt or format variables no longer seems to work in 2015, or for this particular feed I'm using perhaps.

Comment: If anyone reads and needs this in the future: Create your own Feed with the original Feed URL -> go to the options of that Feed -> press Optimize -> Disable "BrowserFriendly" -> Enable "SmartFeed" -> Use this feed now.

Answer (score 50):

From Google Chrome you can update the url like so and you will get the raw xml:

view-source:http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheAppleBlog

Comment: ctrl+U will open it up as well.

Answer (score 18):

In Google Chrome you might need to apply both methods described here at the same time (`?format=xml` **and** `view-source:`):

```
view-source:http://feeds.feedburner.com/TheRegardingBlog?format=xml
```

Answer (score 17):

For the people who still haven't figured it out:

Send an HTTP request without any headers (i.e. don't do it from a browser) to receive the raw RSS feed.

Answer (score 11):

Feedburner feeds send the browser back raw XML, but it also sends a stylesheet that styles the XML markup, so the browser renders the XML as styled content:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~d/styles/itemcontent.css"?>
```

However the data being served up is XML.

So it's completely unnecessary to add query params like `?format=xml`. If you log the response from a request to one of these feeds, or view source, you'll see XML.

Answer (score 3):

@Shimmy @Jordan As a matter of fact it works, if you check the source of the webpage when accessing the page you will notic that normal access provides an HTML page , and accessing with ?fmt=xml param provides and XML feed.

The result keeps being the same in a browser because the XML feed is also formatted using an XSL stylesheet, yielding the same appearance that you would get without using the xml parameter.

Comment: so what's the way to get pure XML in browser ?

Comment: The browser will automatically render it using the stylesheet, so the only way I can see to get it is using the answer provided by sayguh, use the "View source" option :(

Answer (score 1):

Feedburner original feed url for blogger as below
{blogname}/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss

then convert it in flash 
Tutorial at http://alaashaker.wordpress.com/2008/09/09/build-your-own-flash-rss-reader-tutorial-flash-actionscript-30/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `?format=xml` to get raw XML for a feed. Indeed, both ways of retrieving feed XML works. But not always. `?format=xml` however worked on all feed I've tried, but `?fmt=xml` does not. I could guess, `fmt` is legacy parameter, as the feeds where *View feed XML* button available use `format`.

Often, FeedBurner provides XML feed directly (don't be confused with stylesheets used to prettify RSS).

Answer (score 0):

Its quite easy,After searching for here n there I finally found one solution

```
http://www.blogger.com/feeds/blogId/posts/default
```

Note:
To knw your Blog Id,
First, sign in to Blogger. Then choose the blog whose ID you want to find, and click on its name.

From any of the posting, settings, or template pages, you can find your blog's ID number if you look at the URL in the address bar. At the end of the address, you can see that it says blogID=XXXXXX where the X's represent your blog's ID.

Answer (score -1):

The original version of an "unburned" RSS feed can be extracted by viewing the Feedburner feed's source code (or downloading it and viewed as a text file). The original feed is provided between <link>...</link> tag of the <channel> element. It can also be extracted via JavaScript or PHP using XML DOM search.