# Getting XML from feedburner

Tags: ios, xml, feed, feedburner

I'm writing an RSS feed reader for iPhone and I would like to extract raw XML from FeedBurner (ex. http://feeds.feedburner.com/iphone). How can I do that?

FeedBurner API is deprecated. Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting raw XML data from a Feedburner RSS feed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687042/getting-raw-xml-data-from-a-feedburner-rss-feed)