# I am trying to create a flash briefing skill. But i get error everytime when i deploy my skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-flash-briefing-skill

> Error Message: There was an error parsing the feed. Please ensure that
>   the feed is valid JSON or RSS.

Please look into the code below:

```
[
  {
    "uid": "urn:uuid:99098951-c0b1-4881-b3f9-b07d49f594a9",
    "updateDate": "2019-02-1T21:22:14.0Z",
    "titleText": "A hello world audio clip",
    "mainText": "",
    "streamUrl": "https://feeds.feedburner.com/ndtvsports-cricket",
    "redirectionUrl": "https://www.ndtv.com/rss"
  },
  {
    "uid": "urn:uuid:a687993c-5664-4261-a938-79a8526097db",
    "updateDate": "2019-02-1T23:57:33.0Z",
    "titleText": "A hello world audio clip",
    "mainText": "",
    "streamUrl": "https://feeds.feedburner.com/ndtvcooks-latest",
    "redirectionUrl": "https://www.ndtv.com/rss"
  }
]
```

i have create a json file of the above code and uploaded into S3 bucket of aws.amazon.com 
After the i copied the path of the file and than paste in the actual code.

Finally when i deploy with code. I get an error message...

Please help with it...

Goal to create an audio flash briefing skill   without using alexa template. 
even if i put same path in developer portal by using template.. i ended up with same error message.

please help to resolve this or suggest me on add more than one feed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to adopt your URL. Seems that your are not using the real rss path but some website which is build around.
Try an url like this:
https://feeds.feedburner.com/ndtvsports-cricket?fmt=xml
See: [Getting raw XML data from a Feedburner RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687042/getting-raw-xml-data-from-a-feedburner-rss-feed)

You need to give a real rss path and not a path to a website which is showing a feed. (details here: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/flashbriefing/flash-briefing-skill-api-feed-reference.html)